# SQL CASE WHEN on the left side of the equal sign?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

How can I do something like this?

```
WHERE 
(
    1 = 1
    AND
    (
        case
            when p.PickTicket_Number = NULL THEN i.PickTicket_Number
            else p.PickTicket_Number
        END
    ) = '30714871'
```

Here are some things I tried to replace that line

```
AND p.pickticket_number = '30714871'
```

Doesn't return anything.

```
AND i.pickticket_number = '30714871'
```

Returns good data

```
AND coalesce(i.PickTicket_Number,p.pickticket_number) = '30714871'
```

Takes very long to run

Comment: that `coalesce` is the other way round from the code you are trying to fix. `coalesce` means "the first non-null thing in this list of things" - you want `p.` when it's not null, else `i.`

Comment: did you try this with using a temporary table?  then you don't have to do case matching. and compare the performance of your method and temp table option

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IS NULL`, not `= NULL` due to [NULL`'s three-value-logic](https://learnsql.com/blog/understanding-use-null-sql/).

You can use `COALESCE` instead, but your `COALESCE` is fine, but you have the `i.` and `p.` values the wrong way around. It should be like this:

```
AND COALESCE( p.PickTicket_Number, i.pickticket_number ) = '30714871'
```

Answer (score 0):

Coalesce won't perform because it won't use the index. If it's possible write 2 select queries and combine them with `union all`. Or if the logic is ok for you just use: `i.pickticket_number = '30714871' OR p.pickticket_number = '30714871'`

Answer (score 0):

The predicate you are using is equivalent to:

```
where p.PickTicket_Number is null and i.PickTicket_Number = '30714871'
   or p.PickTicket_Number = '30714871'
```

But you are concerned about performance. To make this predicate fast you can add the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on p (PickTicket_Number);

create index ix2 on i (PickTicket_Number);
```

Another strategy to increase the performance is to decouple the query into two separate ones. Each query has a simpler predicate and then you combine them using `UNION`.